# Force ajax .fail() during custom authorization to manage login redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In a MVC application I have a jQuery ajax post to a method in a controller:

```
function initFormForInsert(metodoLoadForm, nomeForm, divForm, widthForm, heightForm, metodoInsert) {
    blockPage();
    var request = $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST',
            url: getRootURL() + metodoLoadForm
        });

    request.done(function (data) {
    //alert(data);
    LoadFormForInsert(data, nomeForm, divForm, widthForm, heightForm, metodoInsert);
});

request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        unblockPage();
        showErrorDialog("Error", textStatus);
    });
}
```

Can I force `request.fail()` in some way?

As I use a global filter for authorization for all my methods in my controllers(code below)
in particular I'd like to throw an exception when I receive this Ajax post and my session variable is null.

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext) {
    try {
        UserToken cUt = httpContext.GetUser();
        if (cUt == null) {
            //session is null
            return false;
        }
        string request = httpContext.Request.Path;
        if (httpContext.Request.Path.LastOrDefault() == '/')
            request = httpContext.Request.Path.Remove(httpContext.Request.Path.Length - 1);
        if (cUt.DeniedActions.Contains(request.ToUpper())) {
            //user is not authorized
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    } catch (Exception) {
        return false;
    }
}

protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext) {
    UserToken cUt = filterContext.HttpContext.GetUser();
    if (cUt == null) {
        //session is null
        if (
            //filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == 302 &&
            filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest"
        ) {
            //filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        } else {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary(
                    new {
                        controller = "Login",
                        action = "Login"
                    })
            );
        }
    }
```

I've modified the JavaScript dialog this way:

```
function initFormForInsert(metodoLoadForm, nomeForm, divForm, widthForm, heightForm, metodoInsert) {
    blockPage();
    var request = $.ajax(
            {
                type: 'POST',
                url: getRootURL() + metodoLoadForm,
                statusCode: { 
                    200: function (data) {
                        //alert(200);
                   LoadFormForInsert(data, nomeForm, divForm, widthForm, heightForm, metodoInsert);
                    }, 
                    401: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        //alert(401);
                    hrefTo("/Login/Login") ;
                } 
               } 

            });

    //request.done(function (data) {
    //    //alert(data);
    //    LoadFormForInsert(data, nomeForm, divForm, widthForm, heightForm, metodoInsert);
    //});

    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        unblockPage();
        showErrorDialog("Errore inizializzando la form per inserimento ", textStatus);
    });

}
```

and the authorize like this:

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    try
    {        
        UserToken cUt = httpContext.GetUser();

        if (cUt == null)
            //session is null
        {
            return false;

        }

        string request = httpContext.Request.Path;

        if (httpContext.Request.Path.LastOrDefault() == '/')
            request = httpContext.Request.Path.Remove(httpContext.Request.Path.Length - 1);

        if (cUt.DeniedActions.Contains(request.ToUpper()))
        {
            //user is not authorized
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    UserToken cUt = filterContext.HttpContext.GetUser();

    if (cUt == null)
    {
        // session is null                
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest")
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.End();
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                    new RouteValueDictionary(
                        new
                        {
                            controller = "Login",
                            action = "Login"
                        })
                    );
        }
    }
}
```

Do you think is ok?

Or another method even if slower could be add when in an if brench 
the check over the session variable

```
   blockPage();
    if (checkSessionVariable()) {
        hrefTo("/Login/Login");

    }
    else {
        var request = $.ajax(
                {
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: getRootURL() + metodoLoadForm,


                });

        request.done(function (data) {
            //alert(data);
            LoadFormForInsert(data, nomeForm, divForm, widthForm, heightForm, metodoInsert);
        });

        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            unblockPage();
            showErrorDialog("Errore inizializzando la form per inserimento ", textStatus);
        });
    }
```

where check session variable is another post which check session variable

```
function checkSessionVariable() {

    var request = $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'POST',
        url: getRootURL() + "/Login/SessionExpired"
    });

    request.done(function (data) {
        return (data);
    });

    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {

        return 0;
    });

}
```

maybe this is a more reliable solution?

Comment: Yes, return a header that isn't `2xx` for example, `500` or `403`

Comment: Thank you Kevin at the moment the code above isn't working maybe due to the lack of the header.. the javascript is Always  request.done.. I try putting the header

Answer (score 0):

Dont recommend to give 500 or 403 errors as a workaround. Remember these are status code which mean N/w failure to Resource not found

Rather, try processing your result from server as a positive response with negative scenario
which means data now need to processed as below

```
request.done(function (data) {
        //alert(data);
        if(data.positive) {
LoadFormForInsert(data, nomeForm, divForm, widthForm, heightForm, metodoInsert);
}
 else if(data.negative){
unblockPage();
        showErrorDialog("Error", textStatus);
}
    });
```

You could pass cookie too for example (pseudo code below)

```
request.done(function (data) {
            //alert(data);
            if(cookie == "positive") {
    LoadFormForInsert(data, nomeForm, divForm, widthForm, heightForm, metodoInsert);
    }
     else if(cookie == "negative"){
    unblockPage();
            showErrorDialog("Error", textStatus);
    }
        });
```